# Is there an equivalent for Cmd-` (switch windows within application) on Windows?

Tags: windows

Alt-Tab switches applications (and can also select between individual windows of each application). Is there a key to switch just between the different windows of an application? I've grown accustomed to Cmd-` on OSX.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> cycles the windows on the n'th pinned taskbar item.

Say, I have Chrome pinned left-most on the taskbar, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> cycles through all Chrome windows.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will cycle through multiple windows or tabs of the same app.

As long as anyone hasn't overridden the default key bindings.

Comment: Yeah, Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs - I'm looking for a way to cycle through windows though.